# (Passive) verbs and nouns

Tags: grammar, verbs, passive-voice, nouns

I have question regarding the use of verbs as "adjectives" for nouns.

When should I use the passive form of the verb? When should I use the standard form of the verb?

For example, when should I use: 「胸に描く夢」、 「胸に描かれた夢」and「胸に描いてる夢」？

Comment: let’s start with how you think to translate each of the three examples you gave. (without knowing what you think they say, it’s hard to give good feedback.)

Comment: Then, at least for me, 「胸に描く夢」is "The dream that is drawn on the heart/chest"; 「胸に描かれた夢」is "The dream that has been drawn on the heart/chest" and 「胸に描いてる夢」is "The dream that is drawn on the heart/chest"

Comment: Each of your translations is using passive voice, but 胸に描かれた夢 is the only version that has a passive voice in Japanese.